# Is there a way to use an overload operator as part of a comparison

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

> Here is my class

```
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <math.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Point {
  protected:
    int x, y;
```

> Here is the overload operater I want to use it compares the difrence between two points.

```
    double operator-(const Point &def){ 
        return sqrt(pow((x-def.x),2.0)+ 
                  pow((y-def.y),2.0));
    }

};

class Circle: public Point {
  private:
    int radius;

  public:
    Circle(){     //Point default const called implicitly
this->x=x;
this->y=y;
this->radius=radius;
}
    void printCircleInfo() {
      cout << x << " " << y << " " << radius << " " ;
    }
bool operator=(const Circle &def){ 
  return (x==def.x) & (y==def.y) & (radius==def.radius);
}
    bool doIBumpIntoAnotherCircle(Circle anotherCircle){
```

> here I want to use the overloaded operater to compare the distance between the two points to the combined radius of two circles.

```
      if (anotherCircle.radius + radius >=   operator-( Point def)    )
    return true;
      return false;
    }

};

int main(){
  const int SIZE = 13;
  Circle myCircleArry[SIZE] = { 5,3,9};
;
  
  cout << myCircleArry[0] <<":";
  ifstream Lab6DataFileHandle;

  Lab6DataFileHandle.open("Lab6Data.txt");
  while (!Lab6DataFileHandle.eof( )) {
 for (int i = 1; i < SIZE; i++) {
Lab6DataFileHandle>>myCircleArry[i];
Lab6DataFileHandle>>myCircleArry[i];
Lab6DataFileHandle>>myCircleArry[i];
cout << endl;
 if (myCircleArry[0].doIBumpIntoAnotherCircle(myCircleArry[i])) {
      myCircleArry[i].printCircleInfo(); cout << " ; ";
      If double operator=(const Point &def)}
{cout <<"*"
}


  }
  }
  Lab6DataFileHandle.close();
}

}
```

> How do I use my previously created overload operator as part of my bool function doIBumpIntoAnotherCircle? Please leave an example in your answer it would be much appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can directly use `operator-` that is inherited from `Point` like this:

```
bool doIBumpIntoAnotherCircle(Circle anotherCircle){
    if (anotherCircle.radius + radius >= *this - anotherCircle)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Or more simply:

```
bool doIBumpIntoAnotherCircle(Circle anotherCircle){
    return anotherCircle.radius + radius >=  *this - anotherCircle;
}
```

Also, this function should be marked `const` and should take the parameter by `const&`, like this:

```
bool doIBumpIntoAnotherCircle(Circle const &anotherCircle) const {
```